# How to bind data in datagridview combobox column

Tags: c#, windows, datagridviewcombobox

Here are contacts but we can have multiple contacts so i want to show a list in combobox

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = MainClass.GetDatabyQuery("select * from tbl");

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dgv_ClientDetail.DataSource = dt;
}
```

I have this method to fetch values from database in datagridview but I want one datagridview combobox column and want to bind data in one dgv combobox and other in dgv texboxes. If anybody know then tell me. Here are three columns Name, City , Contacts. I want to show multiple contacts in dgv combobox column

Comment: You need to elaborate , show your gridview structure

Comment: I can't post image. Don't have too much reputations

Comment: each row has a combobox? and each row has a textbox. Do combobox and textbox belong to different columns?
Explain a bit In detail.

Comment: Here are three coulumns Name, City , Contacts. I want to show multiple contacts in dgv combobox column but Name, and City in dgv textbox column

Comment: I guess that you want to bind the cities into the City combobox for each row ? right

Comment: I want to show multiple Contacts in dgv combobox column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select only `Name` and `City` in `dt`, so that you can do something like,

```
        dgv_ClientDetail.DataSource = dt;
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        dgvCboColumn.Name = "Contacts";
        dgvCboColumn.DataSource = dtContacts; //DataTable that contains contact details
        dgvCboColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
        dgvCboColumn.ValueMember = "Id";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvCboColumn);
```

EDIT:

```
        dgv_ClientDetail.DataSource = new DataView(dt)
                                         .ToTable(true, new string[] { "Name", "City" });
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        dgvCboColumn.Name = "Contacts";
        dgv_ClientDetail.Columns.Add(dgvCboColumn);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_ClientDetail.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboContacts = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
                                                         (row.Cells["Contacts"]);
            cboContacts.DataSource = //Get the contact details of a person,
                                     //using his Name or Id field (row.Cells["Name"]);
            cboContacts.DisplayMember = "Name"; //Name column of contact datasource
            cboContacts.ValueMember = "Id";//Value column of contact datasource
        }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: It is displaying but same contacts in each row.

Comment: Yes...so are you about to set different contact set in each row?

Comment: Yes In new row,there is new member with 2 contacts, I want to show these 2 contacts in his row in dgv combo. If any body has 1 contact and it should show 1 contact in combo

Comment: Not Working. Giving Error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell'

Comment: @user3355213 How about this?

Comment: Check the datasources you are assigning in the `foreach` loop. That is, check the `cboContacts.DataSource` value each time when the loop iterates...

Comment: Also could you please show how do you assign value to `cboContacts.DataSource`?

Comment: Hai @Vanest . your solution really helped me a lot. But i have encountered a problem. When i click the header of a column to rearrange it in ascending order the combobox has no other value. My guess is when i click the header it will reset the combobox value. How can i solve this?

Comment: @Vampire it was because he forgot to tell you to set the `DataPropertyName` to the name of the column in the underlying data, too

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

First just have data key in DataGridView for the contact. And on ItemDatabound Events just use the datakey for filter for each Dataitem with in that DataGridView.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
// Loop through rows and get each combobox

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_ClientDetail.Rows)
{
     DataGridViewComboBoxCell ContactCombo = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(row.Cells[index of Contact column]);

     ContactCombo.DataSource = // your contacts datasource;
     ContactCombo.DisplayMember = "name of field to be displayed like say ContactName";
     ContactCombo.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

Edit: You need to set ValueMember for combobox as well

Comment: It is giving error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell'.

Comment: this means that textbox cell is getting picked, check that you are passing the correct index

Comment: indexes start from zero mind that. If the order of columns is Name, City and Contact . then Contact combobox column has index 2.