# C# - How to populate datagridview with different column style from table?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to ask for a suggestion/opinion/example on how to populate datagridview from table in database. And the datagridview has different style for each column. Let's say for example, I would like to populate a datagridview from **tblData** that contains column **columnA**, **columnB**, **columnC**, and **columnD**. For the first and third column in datagridview; i would like to populate the data in text. But for the second and forth; i would like to populate the data in datagridview combobox. It looks more or less something like this. But the combobox column must be alternate between the text column and the data must be from a table in database..
[image]

How can i achieve this? Any example code can be helpful to me to understand better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Column Types in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is something that really help me a lot [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795816/how-to-bind-data-in-datagridview-combobox-column)