# VB.NET edit Bound Datagridview with columns

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to edit one column in a bound datagridview with a combobox (with fixed values YES or NO). I have the column type already set to DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn (as I have the column filterable from the column header).
Is this at all possible?

I am sure I have seen a video tutorial somewhere where it is done by inserting a combobox inside the datagridview cell and somehow connecting the combobox value and the data source with each other.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "edit a column"?  Change it?: Add one? If it is a boolean value (Yes/No) why not a checkbox?  If the DataSource has the value as boolean, the DGV should create one automatically

Comment: ...above all you should include the code you are having trouble with if you want help with it and ask a better question than `is this possible`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind data in datagridview combobox column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795816/how-to-bind-data-in-datagridview-combobox-column)

Comment: Hi Plutonix. Thank you I have created with editor - so not much code. I have changed my datasource a sql table to bit. the DGV now show True or False,  and in my 1 and 0 in my sql table. Still no combobox